# Error when Building Mex for Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm - says directory that exists does not exist

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex, levenberg-marquardt

I'm trying to build a mex file from a Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm written in C by Manolis Lourakis ([Available here)](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/)). I've done a lot of searching and haven't been able to find a similar problem or a solution to this yet (lots from this forum!).

The author included a C gateway function and I've managed to solve the errors I was getting from the makefile. Now, when I try to build the makefile I am presented with the following error:

```
/var/folders/w6/c4f9x2qn7zb2srs97ngpvflh0000gn/T//mex_112796979375_74657:

line 2: -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64: No such file or directory

Error using mex The command '/usr/bin/xcrun' exited with a return value '0'
```

Which seems to say that /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64, is not a path to the directory 'maci64'. This is strange as when you follow the path, this directory is definitely there. The code I used to build the file was used as instructing in the README file:

```
mex -DHAVE_LAPACK -I.. -O -L</Users/martinmackinnon/Documents/MATLAB/levmar-2.6/levvy>  levmar.c -llevmar -lclapack -lblas -lf2c
```

Where the path with option L, is just the path to all of the files included in the 'levmar' library supplied by the author.

My OS is mac OS 10.12.1 and MATLAB version is MATLAB_R2016b.

I've also tried this on a system operating on OS X 10.11.6 and MATLAB_R2015b, but get the equivalent error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You refer to `/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64` as a "file".  Is it truly a file, or a directory?   If it's a file, that might be your problem:  the `-L` flag is for directories.

Comment: I miswrote that, apologies. It is in fact a directory.

Comment: Please note, read line containing '....maci64, is not a path to the file 'maci64' ' as '...path to the directory 'maci64' '

Comment: 1) I'm reasonably sure that MEX does not have a default include path of `/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64` and the (scant) posted information does not have a `-L` option for that directory. 2) the actual `include` statement for some file in that directory should be posted 3) there is the strong possibility that the compiler does not have read permissions for that directory and/or the desired file within that directory.\

Comment: The problem was solved, the only problem was the use of <and> in the directory path. The include statement didn't need to be included because it was the path to a library which was called as an option in the mex file. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody with the same problem in the future. The problem here was the use of < and > in the directory path for the -L option.